# Powershell Null Value for Permissions to folders

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell code:

''''

```
$Rights = "FullControl" #Comma seperated list, 2 rows, user and path.
$InheritSettings = "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit" #Controls how permissions are inherited by children
$PropogationSettings = "None" #Usually set to none but can setup rules that only apply to children.
$RuleType = "Allow" #Allow or Deny.
$csv = Import-CSV "C:\scripts\test.csv" -delimiter ","
ForEach ($line in $csv) {
    $acl = Get-Acl $line.path
    $user = ('LSS\' + $line.user)

    $perm = $user, $Rights, $InheritSettings, $PropogationSettings, $RuleType
    $rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $perm
    $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
    $acl | Set-Acl -Path $path
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:12 char:5
+     $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I've checked all my variables but I still have this issue. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Based on your code, `$path` is never defined

Comment: The error message indicates that `$ACL` is a null value at that point.

Comment: @trebleCode - It's likely that `path` is a column in the CSV file; `Import-CSV` creates an array of objects where each column is a member property of the object.

Comment: Cheers @JeffZeitlin

Comment: So, how would I integrate that? Would i turn that into an object?

Comment: The users you want to grab for use in your acl's, do they exist?
I say this, because if I test the code, I can get it to work fine with a csv setup with user and path. But if I change the username to some I know doesn't exist in my AD or local machine, it gives the same error

Comment: They do exist. its a prepopulation. as do the paths.

Comment: Pressed enter too quickly, check my edit :)

Comment: So, it could be potential that user name does not currently exist. I see. Thank you!